# Amazon EC2 Elastic IP commands (Private key, CERT)

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to allocate static IP for an account by a command `ec2-allocate-address`, as described in the official doc (http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346). But it returns an error like:

```
[ec2-user@ip-******** ~]$ ec2-allocate-address 
Required option '-K, --private-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)
```

Then I though private-key might be contained in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` which ssh uses, but giving this path as an argument returns:

```
[ec2-user@ip-******** ~]$ ec2-allocate-address --private-key .ssh/authorized_keys
ec2-allocate-address --private-key .ssh/authorized_keys 
Required option '-C, --cert CERT' missing (-h for usage)
```

Is the key file I used correct? And what should I give as CERT part? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For your account you need to set up a specific keypair issued by Amazon for use with the API; this is different than the key (potentially) used to SSH into the box, and in a different format.  You save the X509 cert and key off and then pass the paths (with -K and -C) to the program.

You can also set up environment variables to avoid having to use -C and -K every time.